# PostgreSQL: Creating view of multiple tables in function

Tags: postgresql

I want to create view of multiple table in function using PostgreSQL 9.3 version.

**Example**:

I have following tables in the table name "AllTables":

```
table1, table2,table3
```

And I have following tables in the database:

```
table4,table5
```

Now I need to combine these tables into one and create view within a function.

```
create or replace function fun1()
returns void as 
$body$
Declare
       que varchar;
       b varchar;
Begin
      Select 'select * from ROM ' ||  quote_ident("TableName") ||' UNION'
    FROM "AllTables" a
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables so on a."TableName" = so.Table_name into b;

    que := 'Create view view1 as '|| LEFT(b,length(b)-length('UNION'));  
    raise notice '%',que;
    execute que;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

**Note**: Able to get only one table. Not getting all tables view.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create a `union all` query that combines the data from several tables with identical columns?

Comment: @CraigRinger, Yes! You are right.

Comment: I shouldn't have to guess that - please try to explain things in questions a bit more. Anyway, I'll get this reopened so I can explain what you're doing wrong and how to do it properly.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Thank you so much. I am sorry for incomplete information. Will take care from next time.

Comment: Well, if you get notified that this gets reopened, message me and I'll follow up. The short version in the mean time: use `string_agg` to *aggregate* query strings, using ` UNION ALL ` (not just `UNION`) as the join string. This sort of thing often suggests an underlying design problem though.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Okay fine.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Yes! It got reopened now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is:

- Build each individual query; then
- `string_agg` them together with `UNION ALL` as the joining string.

`UNION ALL` is important, not just `UNION`, as `UNION` may force a sort-and-de-duplicate operation, which is slow.

I will use the `format` function and its `%I` and `%L` format-specififers instead of `quote_ident` and `quote_literal` respectively, because it's massively more readable that way.

---

I have no idea what the stray `ROM` in:

```
'select * from ROM ' ||  quote_ident("TableName") ||' UNION'
```

is. It doesn't make sense. I'm ignoring it. I assume it's probably an editing error, the end of an accidentally remaining `FROM`.

---

So, first, take a query that produces a list of queries for each table:

```
SELECT
   format('SELECT * FROM %I', "TableName")
FROM "AllTables" a
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES so ON a."TableName" = so.TABLE_NAME;
```

then wrap it in an aggregate (`string_agg`) to combine the strings, prefix the `CREATE VIEW` and store the result in your query variable and execute it:

```
SELECT INTO que
   'CREATE VIEW view1 AS ' ||
   string_agg( format('SELECT * FROM %I', "TableName"), ' UNION ALL ')
FROM "AllTables" a
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES so ON a."TableName" = so.TABLE_NAME;

raise notice '%',que;
execute que;
```

---

BTW, needing to do things like this often means you have a bit of a database design issue. You should not need tons of little tables with the same schema like this. It usually means you're doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer01_transactions (
    trans_id serial primary key,
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE customer02_transactions (
    trans_id serial primary key,
    ...
)
```

when you should usually be doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_transactions (
    customer_id integer,
    trans_id serial,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, trans_id)
)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. And yes "ROM" was my editing error, I apologies for that.

Comment: I thought ROM was Read Only Memory (some EE humor here)